# How to localise App name using Xcode 6 (iOS 8)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6

I simply need to localise my app name using Xcode 6. I tried to add:

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "App name";
"CFBundleName" = "App name";
```

to ***localizable.strings*** but it didn't work.

Did I miss anything.

Comment: Do other localized strings work? If not, you have to click on the project file icon in Xcode and add each language to it individually. Also, sometimes you have to reset the simulator for a name change to take effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that it doesn't work is because you need to add the localizations to your `InfoPlist.strings` file, not `localizable.strings`. This [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-102276) explains how and even gives an example.

Please make sure that in your Xcode project settings, you have installed each language that you want to localize and have put the relevant keys inside the `InfoPlist.strings` file of the language that you want to work with.

For example, let's say that you have these keys inside of your `Info.plist` file:

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>Super Fun App</string>
<key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
<string>Copyright © 2014, ACME Inc. All Rights Reserved.
</string>
```

If you want to localize this title so Spanish-speaking users will see the app name and copyright in their native language, then inside of your `es-ES.lproj` folder (which should have been added by Xcode when you added Spanish, or whatever language) you would add this to your `InfoPlist.strings` file:

```
CFBundleDisplayName = "Aplicación Divertidisimo";
NSHumanReadableCopyright = "Copyright © 2014, ACME Inc. Todos los Derechos Reservados.";
```

In the future, if you ever want to modify anything in the `Info.plist` for a specific localization, then the general template to use is:

```
key = "localized value"
```

This is of course not specific to Spanish; the procedure is the same for all languages supported by Xcode.